# Difference between 守らせてあげる and 守ってあげる

Tags: grammar, causation

What do both translate as and why?

守ってあげる is basically protecting something. The original was 約束守らせて上げられなくて御免なさい which I basically translated as, I am sorry that I couldn't (be made) to keep the promise I made with/to you/me?!?

Comment: Please give more details as to why you think that these might be similar, and give your own translation.

Comment: Mamotte ageru is basically protecting something. the original was 約束守らせて上げられなくて御免なさい which I basically translated as, I am sorry that I couldn't (be made) to keep the promise I made with/to you/me?!?

Comment: So... you're asking why this sentence doesn't use 守ってあげる instead? (Please include all information in your question by clicking the edit button. Don't leave your readers guessing what you want to ask.)

Comment: to me 「守らせてあげる」 sounds something like "[I] will let [you] protect [me/something]"  and 「守ってあげる」 -> "[I] will protect [you/something]", depends on the context.. but I might be wrong

Answer (score 3):

> 約束を守ってあげられなくてごめんなさい。

would mean "I'm sorry I can't/couldn't keep my promise (that I made to you)," while:

> 約束を守**らせ**てあげられなくてごめんなさい。

means "I'm sorry I can't/couldn't let you keep your promise (that you made to someone/me)."

守らせる is the causative form of 守る. So, in the first sentence the subject of 約束を守る "keep a promise" is the speaker, and in the second sentence it's the hearer.

Answer (score 1):

私は、あなたに、私を、スズメバチから、守らせてあげる。: I let you protect me from yellow hornets.

This sentence is right, but I never hear or read this kind of sentence. Protection is emergency and serious matter, so almost such situation doesn't allow you to have options. The person who can protect you from something bad would be storonger than you.

私は、あなたを、スズメバチから、守ってあげる。：I protect you from yellow hornets.

This sentence is far more natural. Stronger, elder person than you naturally can say so.